# What is the meaning of the question mark in the named parameter list?

Tags: dart

I found it [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-async/Future/then.html) (please see the screenshot bellow), but I could not find any documentation explaining this.

[image: Docs description]

Comment: Upcoming feature in Dart: https://dart.dev/null-safety

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is used for null safety. The dart team soon will add null safety to the stable channel which you can then also use in Flutter.

When using null safety, you have to specify if you want an object or variable to be null and to be able to do that you can use the new keyword `?`. For example:

```
int? aNullableInt = null;
```

For example:

```
  String? name = null;
  String familyName = name ?? "test" + "haddad";
```

Here `name` can be null since we used `?`, and then to use it you have to use the null checker `??`.

You can read about it here:

https://dart.dev/null-safety

https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

You can test it here:

https://nullsafety.dartpad.dev/